# Can't add new line to text file with all other lines being removed

Tags: python, file-io

I need to be able to add a new line to the end of a simple text file, but I can't. I have a for loop, and on each loop I want to add a new line of text to the end of the file in question, but every time it adds a new line, it removes all the other text, leaving just that line.

This is the code:

```
for item in items: 
    doc = open('mapData.txt', 'r+')
    doc.write(item)
```

I'm using Python by the way.

Thanks in advance, 
James Eggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'a'` (append) mode to, well, append anything you write to the end of the file instead of truncating it.

Also, you propably want to open the file outside of the loop and close it afterwards (`with open(...) as f: ...` would be even better).

Answer (score 3):

Try to open the file in "append" mode:

```
for item in items: 
doc = open('mapData.txt', 'a')
doc.write(item)
```